# Like operator in SAS datastep

Tags: sas

Do we have any alternative for `like` operator(sql) in SAS datastep?
I am using below code for my requirement. but it is not working.

```
IF var1 ne : 'ABC' then new_var=XYZ;
```

Please anyone suggest what is wrong in this or suggest to me what the correct usage is for this situation.

Thanks,

Comment: 'it is not working' is not a useful description.  `It throws this error: xyz` or `It runs, but produces an undesirable result, xyz` is better.  In particular, in this case that code *does* work, albeit to my surprise; so please explain what it's not doing that you want it to do?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `find` function,e.g.:

```
data want;
  set sashelp.class;
  if find(name,'e') then new_var='Y';
run;
```

Answer (score 3):

In datastep, 'if' could be used with 'index/find/findw', but if you want to use 'like', you must use 'where' and 'like' together.

```
data want;
   set sashelp.class;
   where name like 'A%';
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

The colon operator as you've used it only compares values that begin with the quoted string 'ABC'.  Essentially SAS compares the 2 values, truncated to the smallest length of the 2.  So if all the values in `var1` are more than 3 characters, then it will truncate the values to 3 characters before comparing with 'ABC'.

It therefore differs from the `like` function in sql, which is used in conjunction with the `%` wildcard operator to determine whether to look at the beginning, end, or anywhere in the string.

To replicate `like`, you need to use a function such as `find` as recommended by @Amir, or `index` which is also commonly used in this situation.